# Why is my test using the rendered screen from previous test rather than the one rendered in the test itself?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have the following tests:

```
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from '../main';
import LoginContext from '../loginContext';

describe('Main component', () => {
  test('renders the peeps list when the current path is / or /peeps', async () => {
    fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify([]));

    render(
      <Router>
        <LoginContext.Provider value={['', null, () => { return true; }]}>
          <Main />
        </LoginContext.Provider>
      </Router>
    );

    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText('Peeps')).toBeInTheDocument());
  });

  test('renders signup/login when you click the link', async () => {
    fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify([]));

    render(
      <Router>
        <LoginContext.Provider value={['', null, () => { return false; }]}>
          <Main />
        </LoginContext.Provider>
      </Router>
    );

    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText('Peeps')).toBeInTheDocument());
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Sign up/Log in'));
    expect(screen.getByLabelText('Name:')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test('renders new peep when you click the new peep link', async () => {
    fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify([]));

    render(
      <Router>
        <LoginContext.Provider value={['', null, () => { return true; }]}>
          <Main />
        </LoginContext.Provider>
      </Router>
    );

    await waitFor(() => fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('New Peep')));
    expect(screen.getByLabelText('Text:')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test('renders an individual peep when you click on it in the peep list', async () => {
    fetch.mockResponse(
      JSON.stringify([
        {
          id: 3,
          body: 'my first peep',
          created_at: '2018-06-23T13:21:23.317Z',
          updated_at: '2018-06-23T13:21:23.317Z',
          user: {
            id: 1,
            handle: 'Phil',
          },
          likes: [
            {
              user: {
                id: 1,
                handle: 'Phil',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ])
    );

    render(
      <Router>
        <LoginContext.Provider value={['', null, () => { return true; }]}>
          <Main />
        </LoginContext.Provider>
      </Router>
    );

    await waitFor(() => fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('my first peep')));
  });
});
```

If I run each of the tests independently using test.only, they each pass with no problems. However, running the tests as a suite causes the last test to fail, as it can't find the text 'my first peep' on the screen.

What appears to be happening is that it is checking against the rendered screen from the previous test, and I have confirmed this by checking the information given by Jest when the test fails.

What is causing the last test to use the rendered screen from the previous test rather than rendering it within the test itself?